# How to build mpich2 with sctp network module in linux?

Tags: configure, mpich, sctp

What configure options a should use to compile mpich2 (ver 1.1.1p1 or 1.2.1p1) with sctp ?

In my try there is a error when linking cpi.c (small example).

```
/home/op02/mpiopt/sctp/lib/libmpich.a(ch3u_rma_sync.o)(.text+0x20a7): In functio
n `MPIDI_Win_post':
: undefined reference to `PMPI_Group_translate_ranks'
/home/op02/mpiopt/sctp/lib/libmpich.a(ch3u_rma_sync.o)(.text+0x21bd): In functio
n `MPIDI_Win_post':
: undefined reference to `PMPI_Group_free'
/home/op02/mpiopt/sctp/lib/libmpich.a(ch3u_rma_sync.o)(.text+0x25c4): In functio
n `MPIDI_Win_complete':
: undefined reference to `PMPI_Group_translate_ranks'
....
```

My options was

```
../mpich2-1.1.1p1/configure --enable-fast=O1 \
        --host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
        --target=x86_64-secret-linux-gnu \
 --with-device=ch3:sctp --with-pm=hydra \
 --with-cross=x8664secret.cross --disable-f77 --disable-f90  \
        >conf.log 2>&1
```

with `x8664secret.cross` being an output of `getcross.c` program. Host, target, and this file are here to force a cross-compilation. (it is a requirement for this build)

Is sctp in mpich2 in active state and can it be compiled?

Does sctp network module support cross-building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 1.3.1 instead.  I see that Brad Penoff committed a couple of small changes to the build system since 1.2.1p1 was released, so it may be in better shape now.  Alternatively, try using (the rather old) MPICH2 1.0.8, where I believe things were still working.

If the cross-compile step is what's really causing the problem and you still need to solve this problem, you can get more interactive support from `mpich-discuss@lists.anl.gov`.  We can dig in over there instead.

Comment: Glad to see you here, at the stackoverflow. I'm author of #1035-1037.